# me salta esta excepción al recorrer el código 'After end of result set'

Tags: java

Hola estoy aprendiendo java en lo que corresponde a la conexión con base de datos.
tengo este pequeño código, que me da la excepción 'After end of result' set al compilar.

```
try {
        String dbUrl="jdbc:mysql://localhost/sakila";
        String user ="root";
        String pass ="";
        Connection Dbconect= DriverManager.getConnection(dbUrl, user, pass);
        Statement st = Dbconect.createStatement();

        //String insert_db = "DELETE from actor WHERE actor_id = 202";
        //st.executeUpdate(insert_db);

        ResultSet rs1 = st.executeQuery("SELECT * from actor WHERE actor_id < 20");
        while(rs1.next());{
            System.out.println(rs1.getString("first_name"));
        }

        }catch(Exception e){
            //JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, e.getMessage());
            System.out.println(e.getMessage());
        }
```

Agradezco en el alma que me echéis un cable.
Dani

Comment: `after end of result set` es un error de ejecución no de compilación que ocurre cuando intentas obtener la siguiente fila dentro del `ResultSet`, en algún lugar estas llamando `rs1.next()` siendo que el resulset ya terminó de recorrer sus filas o bien, esta ya está vacío

Answer (score 3):

Te sobra un punto y coma:

```
while(rs1.next());{
    System.out.println(rs1.getString("first_name"));
}
```

debería ser

```
while(rs1.next()) {
    System.out.println(rs1.getString("first_name"));
}
```

porque tu código es equivalente a esto:

```
while(rs1.next());

{
    System.out.println(rs1.getString("first_name"));
}
```

Que es lo mismo<sup>1</sup> que

```
while(rs1.next()){

}

System.out.println(rs1.getString("first_name"));
```

<sup>1</sup> En este caso es lo mismo, las llaves pueden tener importancia si se declaran variables dentro del bloque.

Comment: Muchas gracias, no me di cuenta del ;